# how to count multiple users messages in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying display one by one  users message conversation in PHP MYSQL. My script counting all incoming messages from users. but i want to display one by one users unread messages.

example : i want to get like this.

```
user1 unread messages 2

user2 unread messages 6

user3 unread messages 1
```

My script display all users incoming messages in one row Like this all messages - 9

My pm table

```
 id  from_id     to_id    msg   sent_date  read
```

Here is my source code

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
$session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) unread
FROM  pm where to_id=? and read='0'")){
$stmt->bind_param('s',$session_id);
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

echo $row['unread'];
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your SQL as:

```
$sql = "SELECT from_id, COUNT(*) unread FROM pm WHERE to_id=? AND read='0' GROUP BY from_id";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$session_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo 'User ' . $row['from_id'] . ' - ' . $row['unread'];
    }
}
```

Also note that I moved all logics under `if` because if your `prepare` **failed** - it's useless to `get_result` and iterate over result.

Comment: can you one more little help

Comment: With what? Also you can ask another question and accept answer for this one.